# Visual Gap between right most point and chartseries border

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

[image]So producing a Stock Line Chart which shows open, close, high, low prices for a stock ticker. Works perfectly fine, but have a request that I cant seem to figure out if a way to do this.

Users want a larger gap between the right most day on the charts values and the right border of the chart series. Cant seem to find any property of any object that allows us to control how much space between the chart line and the border.

Am I missing something?

So added a picture. Notice the right border for the top chart. Notice the most recent dates value. Users want the right border to be pushed further right and the values to stay in the same position so it is easier to read. Simply add whitespace between the values and the border. Should do on left as well, but right is what is most important.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could include a screnshot of what is and what shall be. Sizes of ChartArea, InnerPlotPosition may help or maybe simply a different X-axis Maximum.

Comment: Updated with image

Comment: Did you try to set the x-axis minimum and maximum? not seeing how the data are added it is hard to tell how to code it, but one extra day on both ends may do it..

Comment: The way to do it, although it seems a hack, was to add an extra day to the chart and set the value to 0. Would be nice if control simply had a way to insert padding between lines and borders.

Comment: Well, that works as well, but the normal way would be not adding a day to the data but to the range of the x-axis, as I told you. And then one could set the InnerplotPosition, but that is a bit more involved as it means giving up on some of the chart's automatisms.